# Publishing Outlook/Excel add-in to the office store

Tags: ms-office, outlook-addin, publishing, excel-addins, office-addins

I have developed an outlook add-in and an excel add-in and created there respective installers.

Now I want to publish these installers to the Microsoft office store(https://store.office.com/). Can anyone provide me the steps to do that?

Comment: If we can't publish an add in to office store,then is there any work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Office store is for Apps only (HTML/CSS + JS). You can publish your add-in in the Windows Store instead. Note, you will need to handle the purchase process on your web site. Also any installers would be available on your site as well. Windows Store just provides a link to your web site for purchasing and installing an add-in.